# Reduction of list through partial application in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there some more powerful version of map for functions with multiple arguments? Thus the length of the reduced list would be `length of original / number of arguments`...

```
tuple a b = (a, b)
map' tuple [1, 2, 3, 4]
> [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

mul a b c = a * b * c
map' mul [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
> [3, 120]
```

I tried to write myself one, but it seems impossible to accept function of any number of arguments.

I would like to have generic version for variable number of arguments, because writing one myself every time takes some time and it won't use loop fusion.

Comment: It's impossible to do in a nice way. In your second example, how would map' know that you don't want a result that is a three element list of functions?  That said, if all types are known some overloading magic can do it.

Comment: @augustss I'm trying this out (see my answer below) and I'm running into some problems making my solution work for polymorphic types. Would you care to expand on the "if all types are known" part of your answer?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to just generate a helper function
for each arity that you need, e.g. for arity 3 functions:

```
map3 :: (a -> a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map3 f (x : y : z : rest) = f x y z : map3 f rest
map3 f _ = []
```

Put these in a utility module so you can import them as needed.
If you want to get sophisticated you can generate them using
TemplateHaskell, CPP macros, or even type-classes, but be careful
about turning this simple exercise into a yak shaving party.

Your example:

```
interact $ unlines . fmap foo . tuple . lines
```

could then be expressed as:

```
interact $ unlines . map2 foo . lines
```

assuming that `foo` has the signature `foo :: String -> String -> String`

Comment: Ye, I am doing that right now, but map3 won't be subject to fusion. Or will it?

Comment: That would be a good, separate SO question. And perhaps someone will answer with a way to determine if fusion has taken place or not.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't, there is no point to write your own list manipulation functions.

Comment: @FordO. That is a bit of a broad statement... Also, what exactly do you mean by fusion? What transformations/rewrites would you like to be seeing? And you could always write Erik's function using list functions that _are_ subject to fusion. For example, `map3 f = snd . foldr (\a (as,bs) -> case as of { [a2,a1] -> ([],f a1 a2 a : bs); _ -> (a:as,bs) }) ([],[])`...

Comment: Fusion doesn't happen by default in functions that pattern match on lists directly. The fusion laws are expressed as [rewrite rules](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-822) which talk about specific GHC functions. You could try to prove your own fusion law (and express it as a rewrite rule yourself), but I somewhat doubt this function can be made to fuse because it looks at more than one element at a time.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Interestingly, the "Stream Fusion" paper mentions towards the end (9.2 Fusing general recursive definitions) the possibility of trying to "fuse general recursive definitions over lists". I don't think anything like that ever got implemented though.

Comment: @Alec Re-reading the paper it seems like the authors are leaving the question open: "It would be interesting to investigate the precise restrictions on the form which can be translated in this way and whether it can be automated". It seems reasonable to me that not _every_ general-recursive function can be fused

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the spirit of defining something like this, but just for the hasochism of it, I'm trying my hand at it. Here is a solution that works, but only for monomorphic types. I'm working on seeing if I can convert it to something involving type families that also doesn't need to be littered with type annotations.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

class Consumer f a b where
  consume :: f -> [a] -> Maybe (b,[a])

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Consumer b a b where
  consume b xs = Just (b,xs)

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Consumer f a b => Consumer (a -> f) a b where
  consume f [] = Nothing
  consume f (x:xs) = consume (f x) xs

map' :: Consumer f a b => f -> [a] -> [b] 
map' f xs = case consume f xs of
                Nothing -> []
                Just (b,xs') -> b : map' f xs'
```

And testing it out

```
> map' ((+) :: Int -> Int -> Int) ([1,2,3,4] :: [Int]) :: [Int]
[3,7]
> map' (id :: Int -> Int) ([1,2,3,4] :: [Int]) :: [Int]
[1,2,3,4]
```

### EDIT

After some thought, I don't think that a better solution is possible (without dependent types). The reason I have to add type annotations everywhere is that I have no way of informing GHC that the two consumer instances I've provided are actually the *only* instances I will ever want (are closed type classes even a thing?) and I can't etch out functional dependencies. This second problem is also why I can't rewrite this as a type family. On a side note though, annotating the function arguments can look a lot nicer now that we have `TypeApplications`: `map' ((+) @Int) ([1..9] :: [Int])`.